# React Native - map array of objects

Tags: arrays, json, react-native, object

I currently have an api returning an array of objects in JSON.

```
Array [
  Array [
    Object {
      "created_at": "2020-06-29T22:16:51.000000Z",
      "id": 2,
      "list_id": 2,
      "lists": Object {
        "created_at": "2020-06-29T22:16:51.000000Z",
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Development",
        "public": null,
        "updated_at": "2020-06-29T22:16:51.000000Z",
        "user_id": 1,
      },
      "status": null,
      "updated_at": "2020-06-29T22:16:51.000000Z",
      "user_id": 1,
    },
    Object {
      "created_at": "2020-06-29T22:23:00.000000Z",
      "id": 3,
      "list_id": 3,
      "lists": Object {
        "created_at": "2020-06-29T22:23:00.000000Z",
        "id": 3,
        "name": "House Tasks",
        "public": null,
        "updated_at": "2020-06-29T22:23:00.000000Z",
        "user_id": 1,
      },
      "status": null,
      "updated_at": "2020-06-29T22:23:00.000000Z",
      "user_id": 1,
    },
  ],
  Array [],
]
```

I'm using React Native to retrieve that data, I now want to output the 'name' to the screen in 
The 'id' should be used as the key.

Here is my code (followed a great guide by Steve Griffith on YouTube).

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, Button, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import { globalStyles } from '../styles/global';

export default class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            data: null,
            loaded: true,
            error: null
        }
    }

    baseURL = 'https://www.example.com/api';

    getData = (ev)=>{
        this.setState({loaded:false, error: null});
        let url = this.baseURL + '/list';
        let h = new Headers();
        h.append('Authorization', 'Bearer XXXXX');
        h.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        h.append('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');    
        let req = new Request(url, {
            headers: h,
            method: 'GET'
        });
        
        fetch(req)
        .then(response=>response.json())
        .then(this.showData)
        .catch(this.badStuff)
    }
    showData = (data)=>{
        this.setState({loaded:true, data});
        console.log(data);
    }
    badStuff = (err) => {
        this.setState({loaded: true, error: err.message});
    }
    componentDidMount(){
      
    }
    render() {
        return (
          <ScrollView style={globalStyles.container}>
                { !this.state.loaded && (
                    <Text>LOADING</Text>
                )}
                <Text>Your Lists Are:</Text>
                <Button title="Get Data"
                    onPress={this.getData} />
                { this.state.error && (
                    <Text style={styles.err}>{this.state.error}</Text>
                )}
                { this.state.data && this.state.data.length > 0 && (
                    this.state.data.map( list => (
                        <Text key={list.id}>
                           { list.name }    
                        </Text>
                    ))
                )}
            </ScrollView>
        );
    }
}
```

At the moment I get no output to the screen of the returned data where I would like the list name.

Can anyone help or point me in the right direction to achieve this please?

I have also looked at using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries to work out the problem however this also just returns:

```
> "0: [object Object],[object Object]"
> "1: "
```

Comment: When using the below ```{ this.state.data[0] } ``` I get '[' returned which is the first (0) characted in the string

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what you are trying to achieve but check this:

```
const nameArray = testArr.map((arrays)=> arrays.map((secondArray) => {
return secondArray.lists.name
})).flat()
```

now you can instead of returning a plain `.name` you can do something like:

```
return (<Text> {secondArray.lists.name} </Text>)
```

in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y1ntzd03/) I mapped through your response and extracted the `name` from the `object_list` object and then I flattened the outputted array because it was a 2D array. Or if you want it in 2d then just remove the `.flat()` from the end of it